# Can't build swift plugin using external lib with ionic 4

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to create an iOS plugin for Cordova which uses [this iOS Pods DFU library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-Pods-DFU-Library).

When I try to build it with Xcode, I get the following error:

> Framework not found iOSDFULibrary

I tried the following:

- Add the framework in `General > Frameworks, Librairies, and Embedded Content`
- Add the framework in `Build Phases > Link binary with Libraries` and `Build Phases > Embed Frameworks` as copied and signed
- Add `$(PROJECT_DIR)` in `Build Settings > Frameworks Search Path`

with all the combinations possible ^^'
Does someone have an idea on what else can be tried?

**Edit**

With cordova when you create a plugin, you have to use a [xml file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework) to configure the plugin.

In this file you can add a `framework` property, so I added the this to the plugin.xml :

- `<framework src="iOSDFULibrary.framework" embed="true" custom="true" />`

I also tried to create a hook for cordova removing and adding again the framework, see [there](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6813#issuecomment-226937558).

With both methods I can see the framework in `General > Frameworks, Librairies, and Embedded Content`, `Build Phases > Link binary with Libraries` and `Build Phases > Embed Frameworks` but I have the same error ...

Comment: Which method of installation are you using to add the library to your project (the Github readme lists Cocoapods, Carthage and SPM)?

Comment: I'm not use to create native plugin with cordova so I don't really now which package manager it uses under the hood. I edited the question with the method I use to try to import the framework